# Перенос сайта на локальную машину

Tags: php, lamp

Есть сайт, к которому есть доступ по фтп. Доступ к бд также есть.
Есть компьютер с LAMP.
Работают php-скрипты в /var/www/html/222.php
Существует ли ли какой-нибудь алгоритм по установки сайта на локальную машину.
Или же можно просто скопировать содержимое сайта в директорию html, и поставить бд сайта для его работы на локальной машине?
Возникла следующая ошибка, не совсем понимаю как ее исправить.

```
Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in
```

В этой строчке.

```
$source_content = preg_replace($search.'e', "'"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
                                   . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\\0', \"\n\")) .'"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
                                   . "'"
                                   , $source_content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вариант "просто" должен сработать, но с некоторыми ньюансами.

Алгоритм:

1. Зайти по FTP/SFTP на удаленный сервер и выкачать все файлы в папку локального домена LAMP - ЛИБО - завернуть все на удаленном сервере в архив через SSH, скачать его и разархивировать в папку локального домена (удобно когда куча мелких мелких файлов и скачать можно по http).
2. Сделать дамп БД удаленного сайта и развернуть его локально.

Теперь ньюансы

1. При необходимости поправить конфиг - например некоторые движки требуют указания в явном виде стартового URL, который у Вас конечно же сменится, также изменятся пути логам, и могут изменится данные к БД.
2. На LAMP может быть (и 90% что будет) несколько другой набор окружения - другая версия РНР и другой набор установленных к нему модулей, поэтому изначально стоит убедится, что версия РНР соответствует серверной и есть все необходимые модули, если же серверную поставить нельзя - то тут уже придется решать на месте и это совсем другая история :).

Comment: Да вы правы, проблема с разными версиями PHP.

Comment: тогда пометьте вопрос как решенный